# Access an RDS DB on a private subnet from an ec2 on a public subnet via SSL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, subnet, private-subnet

I have an instance of AWS RDS running in a private subnet of a VPC.

I would like my EC2 machine, which is running on a public subnet to have access to it via SSL (and not SSH like I saw people suggest. I want to access it directly from the code via SSL).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EC2 instance should have direct access to the RDS instance as long as they are in the same VPC. You just need to open up the security group assigned to the RDS instance to allow ingress from the EC2 instance.

I think you have SSH tunneling (which isn't needed when both servers are in the same VPC) and SSL database connections confused. SSH and SSL would be completely unrelated in this case.

SSL connection support would be a function of the specific database engine you are using. If your database is configured to support SSL connections, then you should be able to configure your database client software running on your EC2 instance to use SSL when creating connections to the database.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks. I didn't know all that info was gathered in one place.

Comment: Correct. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-rds-example has some details of how to do it.